# How to replicate a ng-repeat like functionality in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and been developing in Angular 1.x for past year and a half. Recently I got a project which requires me to build it in jquery only. Now as fate would have it I am going through angular withdrawals and unable to figure out something.
What I have to do is I need a functionality like ng-repeat on my html.
What I have done till now...

```
<div class="c-content-blog-post-card-1 c-option-2 c-bordered">
  <div class="c-media c-content-overlay">
    <img class="c-overlay-object img-responsive" src="assets/base/img/content/stock2/04.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="c-body">
    <div class="c-title c-font-bold c-font-uppercase">
      <a href="page-blog-single.html" id="post-title"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="c-author">
      By <a href="#"><span class="c-font-uppercase" id = "post-author"></span></a> on <span class="c-font-uppercase" id="post-date"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="c-panel">
      <ul class="c-tags c-theme-ul-bg">
        <li>ux</li>
        <li>web</li>
        <li>events</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="c-comments">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 30 likes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="post-content"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my js

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8081/blog',
            method : 'GET',
            error : function(data){

            },
            success : function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var post = data.posts;
                console.log(post[0]);
                $('#post-title').html(post[0].title);
                $('#post-author').html(post[0].author);
                $('#post-date').html(moment(post[0].createdOn).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a"));
                $('#post-content').html(post[0].content);
            }
        });
```

This is the hard coded crude version of what I want to do.Now I would like that whole HTML to be dynamic just like ng-repeat, only coming as many times as number elements I have in my post array.

One very crude method would be to fill the selector.html() with all the html code and then have to iterate as many times as I like, but I am sure there must be some elegant way to do it.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: I found this plugin: https://code.google.com/archive/p/widgets-js/wikis/Repeatable.wiki

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422137/1271037